# How to loop through a series of urls in an iframe using jQuery countdown plugin?

Tags: jquery, iframe, infinite-loop, countdown

The purpose of this code is to loop through the urls and insert the latest one into the iframe.

```
<?php
$count=0;
$urls[]="http://www.techcrunch.com";
$urls[]="http://www.livingsocial.com";
$urls[]="http://www.guardian.co.uk";
$urls[]="http://www.google.com";
$urls[]="http://www.rightmove.com";
$urls[]="http://www.godaddy.co.uk";

foreach ($urls as $count){

?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function start() {
    var changetimer = new Date();
    changetimer.setSeconds(changetimer.getSeconds() + 10.5); 
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: changetimer, onExpiry: liftOff});
    $('#year').text(changetimer.getFullYear());
});

function liftOff() { 
    document.getElementById("mainview").src = '<?php echo($count); ?>';
} 
</script> 
<?php }  ?>
</head>
```

the below is in the body tag

```
<iframe id="mainview" width="800" height="400" src="http://www.holidays.com">
</iframe>
```

The problem here is this code skips through the list of urls so quickly you only see the first one, and the last url. The urls inbetween are so far invisible and the countdown timer only appears once. I am using the jquery countdown plugin.

How do I make this slow down and show each iteration of the count down individually before moving to the next? thank you very much.

Comment: Version 1 of this works too if i remove the last 2 lines of the liftoff function. this is actually further away from what i'm trying to achieve than version 2 though. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your variable scope. `changetimer` var cannot be accessed from litOff function. You could make it global, as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function start() {
    window.changetimer = new Date(); //Declare as global
    changetimer.setSeconds(changetimer.getSeconds() + 5.5); 
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: changetimer, onExpiry: liftOff});
    $('#year').text(changetimer.getFullYear());
});

function liftOff() { 
    document.getElementById("mainview").src = "http://www.google.co.uk";
    window.changetimer.setSeconds(window.changetimer.getSeconds() + 5.5); //Reference global
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: window.changetimer, onExpiry: start}); //Reference global
} 
</script>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: pls see the updated code now. also, i'm not sure whether its running the jquery really quickly, or whether it is skipping it altogether. i say this because when it shows the last url, it does not run the countdown at all. thus the countdown only appears once.

Comment: Thanks to you lots sfor your feedback and answers guy. I found the solution to the problem now in the form of a php parameter for the header: location command. If you use refresh, you can load the same page up again, and each time increment a database pointer. Simples!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all for your feedback and answers guys. I found the solution to the problem now in the form of a php parameter for the header: location command. If you use refresh, you can load the same page up again, and each time increment a database pointer. Simples!